# Function returns function instead of object

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

reI am makijng a script in Typescript, I would like to use the function `convertUnixDate` inside of another function  `getAllSMS` belonging to the same class. I want the value of the `date` variable inside the `getAllSMS` function to be equal to the object returned by the `convertUnixDate`. But for now date equals an empty function instead of the object. Why ?

```
export class SMSManager {

filters: object;
constructor(filter: object) {
    this.filters = filter;
}

public static convertUnixDate(unixTimeStamp: number): object {
    let date = new Date(unixTimeStamp*1000);
    return {
        'day': date.getDate(),
        'month': date.getMonth(),
        'year': date.getFullYear(),
        'hour': date.getHours(),
        'minutes': date.getMinutes(),
        'seconds': date.getSeconds()
    };
}

public getAllSMS() {
    if (SMS) {
        SMS.listSMS(this.filters, function (data) {
            let contacts = {};
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if ((data[i].address).length > 7 && (data[i].address).match("[0-9]+")) {
                    let date = () => {
                        return this.convertUnixDate(data[i].date);
                    };
                    if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(data[i].address)) {
                        Object.defineProperty(contacts[data[i].address], data[i]._id, {
                            value: {
                                "body": data[i].body,
                                "date": date
                            }
                        });
                    } 
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('error list sms: ' + err);
        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Because you explicitly set it to be. Remove the arrow function, keep the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what you have written: the `() => {...}` thing is a function, and it gets stored in `date`.
You should simply write `let date = SMSManager .convertUnixDate(data[i].date);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I use  an arrow function to be able to use the function `convertUnixDate` inside the `getAllSMS` function. If I do `let date = this.convertUnixDate(data[i].date);` I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'convertUnixDate' of null`

Comment: @neiya sorry, I did not see it was a static method. See edit. For static methods you should use the class name. On a side note: ```this``` is null, because the call happens in an anonymous function, which is not bound to the object.

Comment: @neiya convertUnixDate is a static function. So don't call it with `this`. Call it as `SMSManager. convertUnixDate()`